# Index out of range sometimes

Tags: python, function

I have the following code:

```
def right_rounding(min_vol):
    try:
        splitted = str(min_vol).split('.')
        if float(splitted[0]) >= 1:
            return 0
        else:
            return len(splitted[1])
    except Exception as e:
            print("Error code =",mt5.last_error())
            print(e, 'error ', traceback.format_exc())
            pass
```

It works right most of the time but sometimes it gives index out of range

Comment: 1. right_rounding(0) produces an index error.  2) mt5 is undefined, 3) what's the purpose of this function?

Comment: Maybe is should have write include Meta Trader 5 also but you can exclude the try and except part. The purpose of this function is to return the decimals for rounding

Comment: This function does nothing on its own. You need to include what you call it with to get the error, as part of your [mre]

Comment: So what's you question?

Answer (score 0):

```
index out of range
```

It's because `splitted`, which is of type `str`, is of length 1.
You can try printing the list `splitted` and you'll see that you have a list with just 1 element in it, and that would be `min_vol`.

When you split a string with some delimiter (in this case it is `.`), the returned value will be the string itself if the delimiter doesn't exist.

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve with that code, but the issue is that there is no `splitting[1]` because the list doesn't have an element in the 1st index.

If you want to access the last element of the list, you can enter `-1` as the index and it will work.

Comment: So the answer is return len(splitted[-1]) ?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to achieve. You have only posted the error, and I showed you why you have an error. I am assuming that you want to return the length of the last string when you use `len(splitting[1])`. That's why I suggested `splitting[-1]`, if that's what you're trying to achieve, @DragOOneD

Comment: Yes. I changed and I don't get the error anymore. I would accept your answer but my reputation is too low or something